# Gulp permission tasks on Travis CI

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, travis-ci, sudo

I have the following `.travis.yml` file:

`language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8"
before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp-cli
script: npm run compile`

It removes the dist folder on the project and create new dists files. The problem is when Travis CI run the script I get the following issue:

```
> npm run compile
> gulp dist
> Starting 'dist'...
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/dist'
> internal/streams/legacy.js:59
> throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
    ^
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

It seems that Gulp don't have permission to execute mkdir for create dist folder but I can't run sudo with npm or gulp. Any idea to help me? I am grateful.

Comment: Why to do you need to create a root dir `/dist` and not a directory in the current dir?

Comment: This is correct. I need to create the dist folder in the current directory.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this problem out?